# How do I insert an ID into a test class?

Tags: apex, unit-test

I have this SOQL in my class that I am testing:

```
//The ID of a document stored in a Salesforce library
final Id myFileId = [SELECT id from ContentVersion where ContentDocumentId = 'ContentID'
 LIMIT 1
 ].id;
```

My test, of course, does not have access to this data and fails with "DML requires SObject or SObject list type: Id"

How can I get around this?

I tried:

```
Id myFileId = '0129485';
            insert myFileId;
```

But a non sobject type is not allowed.

Comment: your testmethod needs to mock (insert) sample `ContentVersion` and then you would query the inserted record to discover the `ContentDocumentID`

Comment: @cropredy Where do I query the inserted record? in the test class?

Comment: Monika's answer shows this

Answer (score 1):

so we are using the content in some related object right
for example Task object

Then
First, insert the COntentVersion.

```
         ContentVersion content=new ContentVersion(); 
        content.Title='Header_Picture1'; 
        content.PathOnClient='/' + content.Title + '.jpg'; 
        Blob bodyBlob=Blob.valueOf('Unit Test ContentVersion Body'); 
        content.VersionData=bodyBlob; 
        //content.LinkedEntityId=sub.id;
        content.origin = 'H';
    insert content;
```

insert the Task object

```
    Task objTask = new Task();
    objTask.subject='Test Attachment';
    objTask.Type='Quotation';   
    insert objTask;
```

then insert ContentDocuemntLink

```
    ContentDocumentLink contentlink=new ContentDocumentLink();
        contentlink.LinkedEntityId=objTask.id;
        contentlink.contentdocumentid=[select contentdocumentid from contentversion where id =: content.id].contentdocumentid;
        contentlink.ShareType = 'V';
    Test.startTest();
    insert contentlink;
    Test.stopTest();
```

Hope this helps.
Let me know if your Test class works.

Comment: Hi @Monika, I am not using the content in a related object per say. I have a document in a salesforce library that I am selecting in my class, therefore I am not quite sure what to put for "content.LinkedEntityId". Can you offer some advice?